# Water simulation appearing boxy

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm keeping up with a tutorial but when creating the water it has a boxy shape to it. Almost like pixelated art, and this is not the result I'm looking for. The subdivision modifier is not helping, nor the fluid resolution as it keeps its shape. 
[image: Blender Problem] As shown above, from the side.
I would need help making this fluid look more like fluid, less boxy so to say.
[image]

Comment: Could you please upload blend file to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the Viewport Display from "Preview" to "Final".

[image: Viewport display]